# How to get phase shift in this task and in general?

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, phase-shift

So the task says:

> In the serial circuit connected to the 50 Hz frequency alternating
>   voltage, effective voltage values  = 220 V, known voltages L = 660
>   V and C = 500 V. The current in the circuit is 11 A. Determine the 
>   ,  and , and phase shift φ between voltage and current

This is how circuit looks:

[image: RLC Series Circuit]

I have calculated Xl , Xc R L and by applying ohm's rule R = U / I = 220 / 11 = 20 Ω. Xl = UL / I = 660 / 11 = 60 Ω , Xc = Uc / i = 500 / 11 = 45.45 Ω , and then to find L and C I used formula Xl = wL , where w represents angular frequency, w = 2 * pi * f = 100 pi rad/sec, and the same for C, Xc = 1/ wC. And to find phase shift I used formula Φ = tg-1(X / R) = tg-1( ( 60 - 45.45) / 20) = 36.04 °

Can someone help?

Comment: "*The current in the circle ...*" Should that read 'circuit'? Show your calculations and we'll see if we can spot the error.

Comment: Yes it does, I have corrected it

Comment: I have calculated Xl , Xc R L and by applying ohm's rule R = U / I = 220 / 11 = 20 ohm's. Xl = UL / I = 660 / 11 = 60 , Xc = Uc / i = 500 / 11 = 45.45 , and then to find L and C I used formula Xl = w*L , where w represents angular frequency, w = 2 * pi * f = 100 pi rad per sec, and the same for C Xc = 1/ w*C. And to find phase shift I used formula Φ = tg-1(X / R) = tg-1( ( 60 - 45.45) / 20) = 36.04 degrees

Comment: I know it would be much easier if I just send a picture of  calculations but i do not carry phone with me to the library

Comment: Put the calculations into your question rather than in the comments. That way readers don't have to rummage through the comments to understand your question. You can also use HTML `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts but they don't work in the comments.

Comment: How did you determine the voltage across the resistor? I am assuming that all of the elements are in series, is that correct?

Comment: Are you assuming U means U_R?  Known voltages are U_L and U_C.  It's unsolvable otherwise.

Comment: I have edited the question and put in the picture of the circuit, maybe that would help https://imgur.com/VEWZMh8

Comment: Why did you say the voltage across the resistor was 220V originally but now say it is 200V? You need to use KVL with the voltages in phasor form to find the voltage across the resistor, is that what you did?

Comment: yes! 220 V I am sorry

Comment: Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint (again): you need to use KVL in phasor form to find the voltage across the resistor.

Comment: Yes and i got Ur = 60 V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: First take the phase of the current signal as 0.

Then you will know the phase of the voltage signals across each element (R, L, and C) due to the nature of those components.

Knowing the phase and voltage (because they're givens in the problem) across L and C, you can find the values of L and C.

Now you only have to find a resistor value that gives 220 V magnitude across the source.

From there you'll get the phase of the source.

Then, since the problem asked for the phase of the current relative to the voltage source rather than the phase of the voltage source relative to the current, you'll just negate the phase and report that as the current phase. (I.e. instead of saying "the voltage leads the current by *x* radians" you'll say "the current lags the voltage by *x* radians")

Answer (score 0):

Well, the RMS-voltages across the coil and capacitor are given by:

- Current:
  $$\text{I}_{\text{i},\space\text{rms}}=\text{V}_{\text{i},\space\text{rms}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)}}\tag1$$
- Coil:
  $$\text{V}_{\text{C},\space\text{rms}}=\text{V}_{\text{i},\space\text{rms}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\tag2$$
- Capacitor:
  $$\text{V}_{\text{L},\space\text{rms}}=\text{V}_{\text{i},\space\text{rms}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)}}\cdot\omega\text{L}\tag3$$

Using your values we get:

$$\text{C}=\frac{1}{6000 \pi }\approx0.000053\space\text{F}\space\wedge\space\text{L}=\frac{3}{5 \pi }\approx0.19\space\text{H}\space\wedge\space\text{R}=10 \sqrt{2}\approx14.14\space\Omega\tag4$$

I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=w = 2*Pi*50;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{11 == (220)*(1/Sqrt[2])*(1/Sqrt[R^2 + (w*L - (1/(w*c)))^2]), 
   660 == (220)*(1/Sqrt[2])*(1/
       Sqrt[R^2 + (w*L - (1/(w*c)))^2])*(1/(w*c)), 
   660 == (220)*(1/Sqrt[2])*(1/Sqrt[R^2 + (w*L - (1/(w*c)))^2])*w*L, 
   c > 0 && R > 0 && L > 0}, {c, L, R}]]

Out[1]={{c -> 1/(6000 \[Pi]), L -> 3/(5 \[Pi]), R -> 10 Sqrt[2]}}

In[2]:=N[%1]

Out[2]={{c -> 0.0000530516, L -> 0.190986, R -> 14.1421}}
```

And for the phase difference we can look at:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_\text{i}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_\text{i}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right)=\arg\left(10\sqrt{2}+60\text{j}-60\text{j}\right)=0\tag5$$